# How to read 2D array in jni

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

How can I read a 2D double array in cpp passed from java. I want a sample code containing the memory freeing.
I tried the follwing but the app crashes with `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)`error.

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_example_Test
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr, jint width, jint height){

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

        jdoubleArray line1 = (jdoubleArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(arr, j);

        jdouble *img1 =  env->GetDoubleArrayElements( line1, 0);

        // work with img1[]...

        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(line1, img1, 0);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(line1);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: This might sound odd, but don't send a 2D array. Send it as a 1D array and index it with `y * width + x`. Easier to move around and give you a performance boost.

Comment: Can not reproduce. It might have something to do with the ```height``` you're using. Why are you not using ```env->GetArrayLength(arr)``` ?